# Insert new observation by group that is a sum(or weighted sum) in r

Tags: r, group-summaries

i am still new to R and many things are still hard to execute. The community here has been very helpful! I have yet another problem.
1. Creating a new observation for each group that would be the sum(or weighted sum) of certain variables
2. Creating a weighted sum for a variable that has sometimes NA in it

**My dataset:**

```
    df = structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), ID_name = c("AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "CC","CC", "DD","DD","DD"),
    Volume = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 40L, 20L, 
    30L, 10L), Score= c(0.1L, 0.3L, 0.5L, NA, 0.6L, NA, 
    0.6L, 0.2L, 0.6L)).Names = c("ID", "ID_name","Volume","Score"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

I want to 
**1.Create a new observation for each unique ID, that is ID 1, ID 2, ID 3, and ID 4**

**2. Have these new observations be as follows:**
ID     ID_name     Volume                   Score (weighted average)
1       AA          30 (that is 10+20)      (10*0.1+0.3*20)/(10+20) = 0.23
2       BB          80 (30+50)              (30*0.5)/30=0.5 (NA row is ignored in score calculation)
3       CC          90 (50+40)              (60*0.6)/60=0.6 (NA row is ignored in score calculation)
4       DD          60 (20+30+10)           (20*0.6+30*0.2+10*0.6)/60=0.4

I tried mutate function but that doesn't seem to work. Any leads would be very appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: There's something wrong with the `dput` you provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
                ID_name = c("AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "CC", "CC", "DD", "DD", "DD"), 
                Volume = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 40L, 20L, 30L, 10L), 
                Score = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, NA, 0.6, NA, 0.6, 0.2, 0.6))


df %>%
  mutate(HasScore = ifelse(is.na(Score), 0, 1)) %>%
  group_by(ID, ID_name) %>%
  summarise(WA = sum(Volume*Score, na.rm = T)/sum(Volume*HasScore),
            Volume = sum(Volume)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#      ID ID_name        WA Volume
#   <int>  <fctr>     <dbl>  <int>
# 1     1      AA 0.2333333     30
# 2     2      BB 0.5000000     80
# 3     3      CC 0.6000000     90
# 4     4      DD 0.4000000     60
```

Comment: AntoniosK, the elegant lines of codes worked like magic! Thank you so so so much!!!!!!